# Renaming files in folder from a text file

Tags: python

I want to know if it's possible to rename file in folder from a text file
..?

***I explain:***

I have a text file in which we find for each line a name and path (and checksum).
I would like to rename the name of EVERY photo file ( path).

***Extract from text file:***

> ...
>
> 15554615_05_hd.jpg    /photos/FRYW-1555-16752.jpg de9da252fa1e36dc0f96a6213c0c73a3
>   15554615_06_hd.jpg    /photos/FRYW-1555-16753.jpg 04de10fa29b2e6210d4f8159b8c3c2a8
>
> ...

***My /photos folder:***

[image: My /photos folder]

***Example:***

Rename the file FRYW-1555-16752.jpg to 15554615_05_hd.jpg

***My script (just a beginning):***

```
for line in open("myfile.txt") :
    print line.rstrip('\n') # .rstrip('\n') removes the line breaks
```

Comment: Why do you think this would not be possible?

Comment: @EdChum i don't know how i can do that in python i want some help to start

Comment: Have a look at [shutils.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

Comment: @skyline75489 i just open my file and read them line by line

Comment: @wonderb0lt my files (jpg) already exist i just want rename via my txt file

Comment: Did you try `os.rename`? Isn't it working?

Comment: `file.readlines`, [Python's built-in string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) (have a look at split and trim respectively) and shutils.move/os.rename should be all you need to get going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        newname, file, checksum = line.split()
        if os.path.exists(file):
            try:
                os.rename(file, os.sep.join([os.path.dirname(file), newname]))
            except OSError:
                print "Got a problem with file {}. Failed to rename it to {}.".format(file, newname)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to work. Replace the `txt` with reading from a file and for the file names use something like [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os
import shutil

txt = """
15554615_05_hd.jpg /photos/FRYW-1555-16752.jpg de9da252fa1e36dc0f96a6213c0c73a3
15554615_06_hd.jpg /photos/FRYW-1555-16753.jpg 04de10fa29b2e6210d4f8159b8c3c2a8
"""

filenames = 'FRYW-1555-16752', 'FRYW-1555-16753.jpg'

new_names = []
old_names = []
hashes = []
for line in txt.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue

    new_name, old_name, hsh = line.split()
    new_names.append(new_name)
    old_names.append(old_name)
    hashes.append(hsh)

dump_folder = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/dump')  # or some other folder ...
if not os.path.exists(dump_folder):
    os.makedirs(dump_folder)
for old_name, new_name in zip(old_names, new_names):
    if os.path.exists(old_name):
        base = os.path.basename(old_name)
        dst = os.path.join(dump_folder, base)
        shutil.copyfile(old_name, dst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by:

- Looping through all files using [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir). listdir will help you get all file name, with current directory, use os.listdir(".")
- Then using [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) to rename the file: os.rename(old_name, new_name)

Sample code: assuming you're dealing with *.jpg

```
added = "NEW"

for image in os.listdir("."):
    new_image = image[:len(image)-4] + added + image[len(image)-4:]
    os.rename(image, new_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

You can divide your problem in sub-problems:

1. Open txt-file
2. Use line from txt-file to identify the image you want to rename and the new name you want to give to it
3. Open the image copy content and write it in a new file with the new name, save new file
4. Delete old file

I am sure there will be a faster/better/more efficient way of doing this but it all comes to dividing and conquering your problem and its sub-problems.

Can be done in python using a loop, file open in read/write modes and "os" module to access the file system.